# How to format HTML tags and Javascript inside CDATA on XML document on Visual Basic / Code

Tags: javascript, html, xml, cdata

I have XML Documents with html and javascript code written between CDATA.
for example:

```html
<element active='yes' type='Html' instance='LOGO'>
    <body>
        <![CDATA[
            <div class="logos" id="logos">
                <img class="float_right" src='mylogo.png' />
            </div>
        ]]>
    </body>
</element>
```

Another example:

```html
<element active="yes" type="Html" >
    <![CDATA[
        <script>
            //Some javascript code
    </script>]]>
</element>
```

I want my IDE (Visual Studio or VSCode) to recognize my text between CDATA as HTML/Javascript code, and format the code. Do you know any solution for this? I tried to find some extention that do it, but couldent find anything.

Comment: Try this extension [Format Selection as HTML](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=adrianwilczynski.format-selection-as-html).  It looks like you'll have to write your own extension if you want auto-formatting on save.

Comment: Thank you. it's make some of the job. But i also want my IDE to recognize the the text as html/js while i'm wrting the code (with intelisense, autocomplition and so). You know something like that?

Answer (score 1):

I have found the solution:

Change <!\[CDATA\[ to <!\[CDAT A\[ in file

C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\extensions\xml\syntaxes\xml.tmLanguage.json

Now XML wouldn't find <![CDATA[ :)

I also made similar changes in Emmet config:

C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\extensions\emmet\dist\node\emmetNodeMain.js

Make this files 'Read only' in Properties to have no problems after the next VS update.